# HTTP Proxy for Windows server

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, proxy, http, socket

I am sorry that the question is probably not what you thought it is.

I have a box in US on colo which is collecting some data but is fairly easy on the resources. it runs w2008r2. and it has one NIC connected to the public internet.

I live in the uk and we just received netflix. the content is really poor. i want to watch tv shows which available in us version of netflix.

is there a very simple piece of software which can redirect my browser http request from a fixed ip in the uk. so i can run it on the box in the us?

I need this to be simple (as I am not really a networking engineer) and safe to instal (not rendering the box down because of some network configs were wrong (as remote hands are expensive there).

this software not need to be a big server. not necessarily even a windows service. could be some applicaiton which manipulates data and using sockets. and the user will be just one (me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtual Private Networking (VPN) is what you are looking for. I suppose a reverse HTTP proxy might be able to do this but I've never thought about trying it and it probably wouldn't be very performant.

A VPN allows you to establish a connection from your PC to your 2008R2 box in the US as if they are on the same LAN causing any of your traffic to go to the US and then outwards from there, effectively placing your computer (logically, of course) in the US.

A popular, free, software package to do this is [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html) and a Windows installation guide is available [here](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/install.html?start=1). It's not particularly complicated but does have a little bit of a learning curve; there are plenty of OpenVPN guides out there if you run in to any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try SafeSquid.
Installation takes just a couple of minutes.
Also allows you to keep the things secured by configuring User Authentication and/or IP address, so you can easily use from multiple desktops or even devices like phones and tablets, etc.

Bobb wants the US based web-site to consider his UK-originating request, as US-originating.
SafeSquid is a proxy server, that Bobb can deploy on a box in US, and then use this proxy service to access content from the web-site. The web-site will only be aware of the originating source as that of the box in US. Bobb can use Squid or SafeSquid or any other HTTP/1.1 proxy server of his choice. Basically since the proxy servers run on the application layer the connections are created by them to the requested web-site, unlike network-layer applications.
 I mentioned SafeSquid in my suggested solution because it can be easily deployed on Windows - which seems to be Bobbs preferred platform, and achieving basic security goals like authentication can be easily managed.

Comment: I don't think SafeSquid can do what the poster is asking easily. His traffic needs to appear as though it is originating in the US and be reliable/performant, do you have any sources using (Safe)Squid for source address rewriting?

Comment: @nullity please research before commenting on a response.